Aligning Heading and Button on the Same Line Across Different Screens in HTML/CSS
I'm a web development student working on a project. I have two elements on my page:
A heading with a gradient (subheading gradient-text).
A button (next-button).
I need both elements to appear on the same line at the bottom of the page. The heading should be aligned to the left, and the button should be aligned to the right. This works fine on my laptop, but on my campus laptop, the elements do not stay in parallel and their positions shift.
Here’s the relevant CSS and HTML code I’m using:


.subheading {
    font-family: 'Georgia', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 9000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin: 0; 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.gradient-text {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 9000;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #5b42f3, #ff00a0, #ffcc00, #5b42f3);
    background-size: 400%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    animation: gradient-animation 5s ease infinite;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

@keyframes gradient-animation {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}

.next-button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 157px;
    right: 375px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1px;
    font-family: 'Georgia', cursive;
    color: rgb(19, 9, 9);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.next-button svg {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.next-button:hover {
    color: rgb(155, 55, 9);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.next-button:hover svg {
    stroke: rgb(155, 55, 9); 
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="subheading gradient-text"> Lorem ipsum </h2> 

    <a href="home.html" class="next-button">
        Continue 
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6" />
        </svg>
    </a>    
</body>
</html>




I think you can wrap your heading and the a tag in a wrapper div to better control their positioning. Add position relative to the wrapper div and remove the fixed position on your a tag (.next-button) and replace it with position absolute with bottom and right set to 0 you can add transform:translate to shift it 100% from the end (right). Another important thing is to set .wrapper to just fit-content (otherwise As a block element it will take the whole line try removing it and you will see). I hope that is what you wanted to achieve.


.subheading {
    font-family: 'Georgia', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 9000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin: 0; 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    max-width: fit-content;
}

.gradient-text {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #5b42f3, #ff00a0, #ffcc00, #5b42f3);
    background-size: 400%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    animation: gradient-animation 5s ease infinite;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

@keyframes gradient-animation {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}

.next-button {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(100%,0);
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0%;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1px;
    font-family: 'Georgia', cursive;
    color: rgb(19, 9, 9);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.next-button svg {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.next-button:hover {
    color: rgb(155, 55, 9);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.next-button:hover svg {
    stroke: rgb(155, 55, 9); 
}
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2 class="subheading gradient-text"> Lorem ipsum </h2> 
        <a href="home.html" class="next-button">
            Continue 
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6" />
            </svg>
        </a>    
    </div>



